# Three meta tags: process-improvement, code-improvement and improvements

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request, meta-tags

We've found three obvious meta tags waiting for a good flamethrower bath:

- [process-improvement](/questions/tagged/process-improvement)
- [code-improvement](/questions/tagged/code-improvement)

and the worst offender:

- [improvements](/questions/tagged/improvements)

They are invariably being used for off-topic questions (process or project management, code review requests, etc). Please do burninate these at the earliest convenience!

Comment: Can you chuck [tag:improvements] in there as well?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Ooh yes, juicy flame bait!

Comment: And now I'm hungry for some juicy, flame-cooked bbq brisket chili. But seriously. How about [code-review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review)? It's not *exclusively* flame-bait, but nearly.

Comment: Where are all the tags for making code worse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been doing a little improvement :-).

- <s>[improvements](/questions/tagged/improvements)</s> is dead.
- <s>[process-improvement](/questions/tagged/process-improvement)</s> is dead.
- <s>[code-improvement](/questions/tagged/code-improvement)</s> is dead.

I guess that answers the question but I'd still like to get rid of the other tags I came across, whilst doing this, that deserve burnination:

- [project-management](/questions/tagged/project-management) 1,714 Having looked through them most of them are clearly off-topic/not constructive. There are [379 open questions with a score less than 3 and without an answer with a score of more than one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/94001), which might be candidates for a bashing?
- [agile-project-management](/questions/tagged/agile-project-management) <s>66 61 54 50</s> 46 (<s>15 25</s> 24 closed) - I've voted on everything I can/will.
- [project-management-tools](/questions/tagged/project-management-tools) <s>44 34 27 23</s> 16 (<s>11 4</s> 1 closed) I've removed the tag and cleaned up the questions that don't need it (mostly Git/SVN problems) and left it on the others (all recommendations) that I've voted to close/delete as appropriate. The rest need some community help to close before the tags can be removed.
- [collaboration](/questions/tagged/collaboration) is alive with 325 questions, *sigh*.

Comment: I've closed and voted to delete some more, we'll get this cleaned up.

Comment: `process-improvement` is now gone.

Comment: I keep going through the smaller lists, voting to close and delete where I can.

Comment: Hrmz; [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409849/what-is-project-management-software-and-which-packages-lets-me-manage-features) didn't receive any more close votes; my votes have expired on that one now. So did several others. :-(

Comment: I've just seen your comment @Martijn; I'm experiencing the same problem :-(. I guess flagging them all would piss off some people... so I'm just going to have to hope that others VTC and they get picked up in the queue.

Comment: Collaboration is *not* dead; there are 332 questions, of these are 33 closed.

Comment: ARRRGGHHHH who did that @Martijn? It _was_ dead.

Comment: No idea, the [oldest collaboration question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265/best-practice-collaborative-environment-bin-directory-svn) shows no history of recent changes; last active 4 years ago.